# htaccess rule to make index.php be served instead of index.html when go to http://localhost

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, localhost

Could someone provide an .htaccess rule such that my index.php overrides my index.html?

Meaning that index.php, and not index.html, is served when I go to `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work instead...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

That will do the job:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

In case there is no index.php the index.html file will be served instead.

Comment: This is the right way to do it. If migrating a site where there may be explicit links to index.html then do the RewriteRule as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the apache configuration file (or .htaccess), set DirectoryIndex to index.php, instead of index.html

Here is an example:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess6.shtml